# Cosa significa "scaricare a ruota"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Dopo la recita, vi diedi uno strappo in auto, e il caso, un po' guidato dalla volontà di entrambi, fece sì che i tuoi amici scendessero per primi alla loro destinazione, e Luigi **fosse scaricato a ruota**.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire "scaricare a ruota" in questo brano. Ho cercato il significato di questa espressione su Internet, ma non ho trovato niente. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scaricare a ruota in questo caso significa scaricare subito dopo. Qui "a ruota" indicherebbe che l'azione è ripetuta dopo un breve intervallo di tempo.

Per esempio (da http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/R/ruota.shtml :

> ***Seguire a ruota***
>
> Fig.: venire subito dopo, seguire a brevissima distanza, pari a quella di una ruota di bicicletta; anche ottenere un risultato appena inferiore a quello di un altro, o **in tempi leggermente più lunghi**.
>       Viene dal linguaggio delle corse ciclistiche, dove indica due corridori che giungono al traguardo con uno scarto minimo, corrispondente al diametro della ruota della bicicletta.
>
> Var.: arrivare a ruota; tenere la ruota; stare a ruota; andare a ruota; venire a ruota

Per quanto riguarda "stare a ruota": il dizionario lo riporta come variazione del "seguire a ruota" io lo ho trovato anche col significato di "tenere il passo" ed in alcuni casi anche come "dipendenza" o, in gergo, "crisi d'astinenza". Non sono sicuro se ci sia un'influenza dialettale o no nei differenti significati (eventualmente lo tolgo dalla citazione se complica le cose)